# Using sum(), count(), and "group by" in Berkeley DB

Tags: sql, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

How do I use `sum()`, `count()`, and `group by` in Berkeley DB? Is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which API are you using? If you're using the key/value API, then you will need to implement those functions yourself, essentially by scanning the database using a cursor. If you are using the [SQL API](http://bit.ly/fdaodv), then you can simply do a "SELECT sum(), count() ... GROUP BY ..." SQL statement.

You may want to post questions like this to the [Berkeley DB forum](http://bit.ly/g5Fkbz).

Comment: @user633117 don't forget to upvote when you have sufficient rep.